# How to set specific settings in Django from a global settings module

Tags: python, django, module, settings

we are trying to identify best practices to set Django settings for the different envs we would like to use such as local dev, staging and production.

Reading around, we found two main *technics* used:

1. The settings_local.py file, not versioned, imported at the end of the main settings.py file
2. The settings module way, where settings becomes a python module, and specific env.py files are inside it [source here](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html#building-a-perfect-django-settings-module)

We would prefer the second way, since it seems very modular and "python" way, but, being the guide still incomplete, how to say Django which module to use for each different env?

Do you think it is a good way to manage Django settings?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's also normal to use both approaches. Eg, you can have different environments, like "development", "staging", "production" and local-only settings on each developers machine.

Usually, `settings_local.py` just imported at the end of `settings.py` from current directory (or special directory that you use for configuration files).

For managing different environments, we use `env` variables. It looks like this:

```
$ export MY_PROJECT_ENV=production
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["MY_PROJECT_ENV"]
'production'
```

In `settings.py` this looks like

```
ENV = os.environ.get("MY_PROJECT_ENV", "production")
LOGGING_LEVEL = "debug" if ENV == "development" else "error"
```

For more convenient operations with `export`, you can add all such exports to your `~/.profile` (or similar by functionality file).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's an interesting method, but how should I set the variable, for example, on the production server? Finally, do you also know how to set each specific env once set the settings module like in method #2 ?

Comment: @caruso_g In my answer I described how you can export variable on server. Second question is not clear for me.